# Prime Number Recursion- How Does It Work? (Python)

Tags: python, function, recursion, primes, primality-test

I was wondering how this program knows if a number is prime or not. I understand that it checks for remainders to find even numbers to divide by but how does it know that a number has only 2 factors? I'm new to the concept of recursion so a explanation of the steps would be helpful thank you.

**Code**

```
def RecIsPrime(m):
    """Uses recursion to check if m is prime."""
    def PrimeHelper(m, j):
        """Helper Function to iterate through all j less than m up to 1 to look for even divisors."""
        if j == 1:  # Assume 1 is a prime number even though it's debatable.
            return True
        else:
            #do this task if both conditionals are true
            #else break and return false.
            return m % j != 0 and PrimeHelper(m, j - 1)
    return PrimeHelper(m, m -1)
```

**Source**

https://github.com/hydrogeologist/LearningPython/blob/master/_recursion%20example%20in%20Python

Lines: 184 to 194

Comment: Your question focuses on even numbers in a way that the code doesn't. The code focuses on *smaller* numbers, which might or might not be even. The code itself is a shockingly inefficient trial division approach to primality testing and is worthless other than perhaps as a puzzle involving recursion.

Comment: @JohnColeman "even divisors" was probably intended to mean "evenly-dividing numbers".

Comment: Did any of the answers suit your needs? Could you leave a comment or accept an answer?

Answer (score 2):

It checks whether there's any number from m - 1 down to 1 that divides m, it doesn't check just even numbers.

EG, for `RecIsPrime(10)` you will have these nested functions call:

```
PrimeHelper(10, 9) = 10 % 9 != 0 and PrimeHelper(10, 8)
↪ PrimeHelper(10, 8) = 10 % 8 != 0 and PrimeHelper(10, 7)
  ↪ PrimeHelper(10, 7) = 10 % 7 != 0 and PrimeHelper(10, 6)
    ↪ PrimeHelper(10, 6) = 10 % 6 != 0 and PrimeHelper(10, 5)
      ↪ PrimeHelper(10, 5) = 10 % 5 != 0 == false
```

`10 % 5 != 0` is `false`, so the right hand side of the `and` won't be evaulated. `PrimeHelper(10, 5)` will return `false` and doesn't continue the recursion.
In `PrimeHelper(10, 6)` you get `10 % 6 != 0` to be `true`, but we've just seen `PrimeHelper(10, 5)` to be `false` so this will return false as well, and so will all the other calls.

Comment: This is a good answer as it helps to visualize the recursion .

Comment: Thank you this helped me visualise it in a way I understand.

Answer (score 0):

This code is a *tail recursion* case, i.e. it can be seen as a recursive way to perform iteration. Note that Python doesn't actually interpret it that way (which would be an optimisation), but it is still helpful to see it like that:

See how every recursive call of `PrimeHelper` has the same value for *m*, but has a value for *j* that is one less compared to the value it had in the previous call.

So the code is comparable to this variant:

```
def RecIsPrime(m):
    for j in range(m-1, 1, -1):
        if m % j == 0:
            return False
    return m > 1
```

In this variant every iteration corresponds to a recursive call in the original code. Note that `return False` breaks the chain, which is done by `m % j != 0` in the original code, i.e. there it serves two purposes:

1. Return `False`
2. Don't call `PrimeHelper` anymore

It is important to note that the two variants do not behave the same way when you call `RecIsPrime` with an argument of 1 or less. In those cases the recursive code can produce a *"division by zero"* error (when `RecIsPrime(1)`) or recurse for ever (e.g. `RecIsPrime(-1)` or any lesser value). This is a bug. To correct it change:

```
return PrimeHelper(m, m -1)
```

by

```
return m > 1 and PrimeHelper(m, m -1)
```

which also fixes the case for 1: it is more than just *"debatable"* whether 1 is prime or not: it is definitely not.

Comment: Note that while this is written with the intent of performing tail-recursion Python doesn't actually support it.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that, @AndreaAmbu.

Comment: even in a TCO-capable language, whether or not the original code is tail recursive would hinge on the implementational details of `and`. On itself it is tail-rec *modulo-cons*, where the actual *cons* used is the `and` (which can also be the *list-constructing* `cons`, or even `+`, etc.).